# What number continues the sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

What number continues the sequence?

1 2 4 8 16 31 ?

Hint:

> The numbers are the answers of a mathematical question.

Comment: Please see [Number-Sequence Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5712/25966)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next number is

> 57

Because these are the

> Maximal number of regions obtained by joining n points around a circle by straight lines

Answer (score 6):

The answer could be

> 57: the number of regions a circle is divided into by $n$ points.

or

> 61: the "Pentanacci" numbers, where each number is generated from adding the previous five (and numbers before the start of the sequence are 0).

or perhaps

> 62: the divisors of 492, the third perfect number.

or even

> 46: the [Stoehr sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StoehrSequence.html) for $h=4$.

or maybe

> 60: the number of binary sequences of length $n$ not containing "01110".

All of these were found with the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2c2%2c4%2c8%2c16%2c31), and they all give different answers. I *assume* you're looking for the first one, but the second is plausible as well.

Comment: the second one is not a mathematical question. It is a number sequence.

Comment: I don't thing my sequence was a nice sequence anyway tho:D

Answer (score 2):

These are

> (maximal) numbers of regions formed by placing 1,2,... points on the circumference of a circle and joining them with straight lines. This equals $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{4}$, which is the same as $2^n$ for $n\leq4$, but after that grows more slowly.

[EDITED because I'd slightly fluffed the description.]